# Type inference in generic structs in Go

Tags: go, generics, type-inference

Consider the following code

```
import "fmt"

type key1 int
type key2 string
type value int

type m1 map[key1]value
type m2 map[key2]value

type A[key key1 | key2, t ~map[key]value] struct {
    m t
}

// I chose an example involving looping through a map to highlight the need of defining the map itself in the constraint.
func (a A[t, key]) foo() {
    for k, v := range a.m {
        fmt.Println(k, v)
    }
}

func main() {
    A[key1, m1]{
        m: m1{1: 1},
    }.foo() // prints: 1 1

    A[key2, m2]{
        m: m2{"one": 1},
    }.foo() // prints: one 1
}
```

[demo](https://go.dev/play/p/JbzEJbAJbYA)

In a more complex setting, I need to write a "generic expression" that is much longer and I need to repeat it many times (once for each method). I would therefore love to replace it with a shorter expression. I have tried things like

```
type constrainKey interface {
    key1 | key2
}

type constrainMap interface {
    map[constrainKey]value
}

type A[t constrainMap] struct {
    m t
}

func (a A[constrainMap]) foo() {
    for k, v := range a.m {
        fmt.Println(k, v)
    }
}
```

But it fails to compile. Can you help me out to find a shorter / simpler constrain expression? Help me to find an interface definition that can, on its own, represent the constraint `key key1 | key2, t ~map[key]value`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to simplify the instantiations here.

As long as you want to parametrize the key types, you must specify a separate type parameter for that. As long as you have two type parameters on a struct definition, you must always instantiate both of them.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/62460) about extending type inference to generic types, but the language doesn't support it yet.

Type inference does work with functions. So, the only possible workaround is to define a function that accepts the generic types as arguments:

```
func DoFoo[K key1 | key2, M ~map[K]value](m M) {
    A[K, M]{
        m: m,
    }.foo()
}
```

And then just call it with the desired arguments:

```
func main() {
    Foo(m1{1: 1})
    Foo(m2{"one": 1})
}
```

Obviously you can always return `A` from this function, in case you need to use the struct afterwards.

```
func DoFoo[K key1 | key2, M ~map[K]value](m M) A[K, M] {
    a := A[K, M]{
        m: m,
    }
    a.foo()
    return a
}
```

Playground https://go.dev/play/p/tOKO8ic1hZX